# Убрать дупликаты с определённым условием SQL

Tags: sql

Есть таблица SQL:

```
Имя   Время  Описание
Тест1   15      Текст
Тест2   22      Текст
Тест1   5       Текст
Тест2   24      Текст
```

Как вывести DISTINCT с наибольшим значением "Время"? Я использую СУБД CrateDB.

```
  Имя   Время  Описание
  Тест1   15      Текст
  Тест2   24      Текст
```

Comment: CrateDB поддерживает и CTE, и оконные функции.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dt4tmtsrTMdYTQsCDdSSi5/0